# AndroidアプリでGmailを使用し自動的にメール送信を行う方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

AndroidアプリでGmailを使用し自動的にメール送信を行う方法を教えて下さい。
（「OAuthを利用した認証」方法を教えて下さい）

詳細：
　お世話なっております。

今回、GPSを利用してある条件に当てはまった際、メールを自動送信するアプリを制作しております。
　以下のサイトを参考にさせて頂きGmailにアクセスするところまでは動作できたのですが、
　（http://kawaidesu.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/04/071658）
　（サンプル：kawai-norimitsu/eclipse_app_mail）
　Gmailから「セキュリティの弱いアプリからのアクセス」として拒絶されてしまいました。
　本件について調査すると、「設定を変更（非推奨）」か「OAuthを利用した認証」が必要と解りました。
　これからのことも考え「OAuth」を取得しようと考えたのですが、これまで「OAuth」を使用したことが無く、一から勉強しているのですが断片的な情報しか検索できず思い違いをしていないか不安になっております。
　この問題をご解決された方が降りましたらアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

追記：
勉強を進めた結果、以下のサイトを参考に「gmail api」と「authToken」の実装方法について調べて、「authToken」の取得まで進む事が出来ました。
http://diary.syarihu.net/2015/05/androidandroidoauthoauthhelper.html

しかし、以下の問題について詰まっております。
ご存知の方がおりましたらアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

・習得した「authToken」をどのように組み込めばよいのでしょうか？
　「kawai-norimitsu/eclipse_app_mail」の「MailSender（session）」の部分を「authToken」でどのように変更すればいいのか？それとも全く違う実装になるのか？を勉強中です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 本問題を解決することが出来ました。
http://qiita.com/daisy1754/items/788cf32d9379746bba14
を参考にし動作できるようになりました。
お騒がせいたしました。